# remove wpf hyperlink when

Tags: c#, wpf

I have a program that requires a license key to register it. There are 2 links side by side in the menu that are for the license. One is "Buy Now" which takes a person to a webpage to get the license key. The user then clicks the other link "Enter License Key". When the license key is verified the "Enter License Key" link is no longer visible in the menu. I cannot figure out how to have the other link "Buy Now" to not be visible when the license is verified. I know the "Buy Now" link name needs to be in the code for the license key verification and set to visible == false when license key == True but so far it has not worked. I would appreciate if someone could advise on how to make it work. The license function code is listed below. The Buy Now link name is: _BuyNowMenuLink

```
 private void EnterLicenseKeyMenuItem_Click(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
    {
        LicenseKeyWindow window = new LicenseKeyWindow
                                      {
                                          Owner = this
                                      };
        if (window.ShowDialog() == true)
        {
            Title = Title.Replace(_UnregisteredText, null);
            _BtnSave.IsEnabled = true;
            _EnterLicenseKeyMenuItem.Visibility = Visibility.Collapsed;
            MessageBox.Show(this,
                            "You version of the program was registered successfully.",
                            "Success",
                            MessageBoxButton.OK,
                            MessageBoxImage.Information);
        }
    }
<Menu Background="#dce0de" >
                <MenuItem Name="_BuyNowMenuItem" />
            <Hyperlink TextDecorations="None"
                RequestNavigate="HandleRequestNavigate9" Name="h9" 
                NavigateUri=" http://www.background-magic-express.html ">
                    <Hyperlink.Style>
                        <Style TargetType="Hyperlink"
                                   BasedOn="{StaticResource {x:Type Hyperlink}}">
                            <Setter Property="Foreground" Value="Black"/>
                        </Style>
                    </Hyperlink.Style>
                    Buy Now                                     
            </Hyperlink>
            </Menu>
```

Comment: Does `_BuyNowMenuItem.Visibility = Visibility.Collapsed` not work?

Comment: It does not work. I also tried _BuyNowMenuItem.Visibility.Hidden and it did not work either.

Comment: Well, it should work... Are you sure you're not setting it back to Visible somewhere else?

Comment: I'll do a double look at the code and let you know.

Comment: It is not set back to visible. I am placing the _BuyNowMenuItem right below the _EnterLicenseKeyMenuItem.Visibility code line. I will add my xaml code to the code above maybe something is incorrect there?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In your XAML, `_BuyNowMenuItem` is *not* the hyperlink; it's an empty `MenuItem`, and it's the one you hide when you do `_BuyNowMenuItem.Visibility = Visibility.Collapsed`. The "Buy now" hyperlink is named "h9", so if you want to hide it you must do `h9.Visibility = Visibility.Collapsed`

I suspect you intended to include the `Hyperlink` in the `MenuItem`, but it's not what you did, since you closed the `MenuItem` element before adding the `Hyperlink` to it.

Comment: Thank you very much! Funny how a person can look at something and not see it. I appreciate your help! Thanks!